Does the Born quantum master equation preserve positivity?
The Born quantum master equation (QME),
$$
\frac{d \rho}{d t} = -g^2\sum_{\alpha,\beta} \int_{0}^{t} d\tau \mathcal{B}_{\alpha\beta}(\tau)[A_\alpha(t),A_\beta(t-\tau)\rho(t-\tau)] +h.c.
$$
is a perturbative (valid for weak system-bath couplings), non-Markovian, QME for the system density matrix [Lidar, 2019]. It assumes the Born approximation, which requires that the density matrix of the environment remains stationary at all times.
To describe physically-correct dynamics, the QME must in particular preserve the positivity of the density matrix. It is known that both, the more general, exact Nakajima-Zwanzing QME, and the Markovian Lindblad QME (obtained from the Born QME via the Markovian and rotating-wave approximations) preserve the positivity of the density matrix, while the Bloch-Redfield QME (obtained via the Markovian approximation only) does not. However, I haven't found any results regarding the Born QME itself. Does the Born QME preserve positivity?
